# Meaning of devil's advocate

Tags: legal-terms

What is the meaning of devil's advocate. Is it same as falsification/falsifiability ?

Comment: Shows zero research

Answer (score 6):

A "[devil's advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate)" is someone who makes an argument that is contrary to the interests that the person who is making the argument is supposed to uphold, as a tool for testing the strength of the arguments being made in support of those interests. It is a tool to help advocates avoid making [strawman arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) by forcing them to prepare for the best arguments that can be made to counter their own arguments, and to help a group of likeminded advocates overcome [groupthink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink).

The colorful language has its roots in Roman Catholic canon law, where a devil's advocate is appointed to challenge and test arguments in favor of elevating someone to Sainthood, although it now has a much broader meaning.

The term is often used by someone to clarify the role that they are taking when they engage in this activity, so that they are not reviewed by their colleagues as disloyal or traitorous to their cause by looking at an issue from their opponent's perspective, and by calling attention to the strengths of their opponent's position.

> Is it same as falsification/falsifiability?

No.

Comment: A similar concept outside advocacy is [red team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_team).